# Not able to iterate above 50 when using CSV in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

MY Jmeter Scripts runs for only 50 users even though i have mentioned 60 users in CSV , I have configured number of threads to 60 at the Thread Group Level

For the Thread 51  it starts showing  - Stop Thread seen: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file detected

[image]

Comment: Can you show your CSV and CSV component in JMeter?

Comment: @user7294900 added the CSV component  , CSV has users in the format-      prasad,password

Answer (score 3):

It is expected as you have:

- Recycle on EOF: `False`
- Stop Thread on EOF: `True`

Set `Recycle on EOF` to `True` and JMeter will re-use the same file from the beginning.

More information:

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)